# retrive data from sqlite by weeks

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app that register daily some info into SQLite DB.
My table looks like this:

**id**     **data**    **counter**

and the script to create my table is:

```
CREATE_TABLE_SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RESULTS_NAME + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATA + " TEXT," + KEY_COUTER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" + ")";
```

I insert today's date, converting it in string using `SimpleDateFormat` and counter,  everytime I press the button X. If current date is the same like last row in this DB table I just update counter column doing count++.

I can retrieve all info from DB without problems. But I'd like to retrieve `SUM(counter)` by weeks, for exemple `26/Apr/2015 -- 2/May/2015` and so on for all my DB records.
I am trying to build my own algorithm but I realized that I am a bit confused and my deadline is soon, so I'd like to find a easy way.

Maybe somebody had the same situation, please help me.

Comment: It will be easier to compare dates, if you store it in timestamp format.

Comment: Does sqlite allows us to use datatype data?

Comment: no it does not support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change a bit my table, so now it's look like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RESULTS_NAME + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATA + " INTEGER," + KEY_COUTER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" + ")";
```

and the method for retrieving my `SUM(counter)` for a period of time is:

```
    // Getting range
public List<Dates> getRange(long dataStart, long dataEnd) {
    List<Dates> datesList = new ArrayList<Dates>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RESULTS_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_RESULTS_NAME, new String[]{KEY_ID,
            KEY_DATA, KEY_COUTER}, KEY_DATA + " BETWEEN ? AND ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(dataStart),String.valueOf(dataEnd)},null, null, null, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

        Dates dates = new Dates();
        dates.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        dates.set_data(cursor.getLong(1));
        dates.set_counter(cursor.getInt(2));
        // Adding contact to list
        datesList.add(dates);
    }
    // return dates list
    return datesList;
}
```

and call this generic method in my dao class:

```
public int retrieveRange() {
    List<Dates> dates = dataBase.getRange(data1, data2);
    int i = 0;

    for (Dates dts : dates) {
        i += dts.get_counter();
    }

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your date in this format '2015-04-24 00:00:00' and try below query.

```
select SUM(counter) from dates1 
where dates >= Datetime('2015-04-26 00:00:00') 
and dates <= Datetime('2015-05-02 00:00:00')
```